# blob image display in flutter from mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, image, flutter

how do we get image from MySQL database and display in flutter?
I have tried many things but I am unable to do it. I converted the blob image but that too isn't working.

and also I am not able to display the whole data even if it is in listview...!
Below is the code for it -:

```
import 'package:education/Screens/Home_View.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';




class ScheduleClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScheduleClassState createState() => _ScheduleClassState();
}

class _ScheduleClassState extends State<ScheduleClass> {




  var course_id, class_id, dates, schedule_image;
  var data;

  Future<http.Request> getData() async
  {
    var client = new http.Client();
    final response = await client.get('http://192.168.0.104:5000/class_schedule');
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    setState(() {
      dynamic courseid = responseJson['courseid'];
      dynamic classid = responseJson['classid'];
      dynamic date = responseJson['date'];
      dynamic scheduleimage = responseJson['scheduleimage'];
      var blob = responseJson['scheduleimage'];


      Uint8List image = Base64Codec().decode(blob);      // image is a Uint8List

      class_id = classid;
      course_id = courseid;
      dates = date;
      schedule_image = image;
      data = responseJson;



    });


    print(responseJson);
    client.close();
    // return responseJson;
  }




  int i = 1;



  @override
  void initState(){
    getData();
    super.initState();
    print([class_id].length);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print({class_id}.length.toString());

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Class Schedules'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 15,
        leading: InkWell(
          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => homeView()
            ));
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        itemCount: [class_id].length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Card(
              elevation: 10,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [

                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Text(
                      '${dates[i]}',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),


                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 500,
                      child:  Center(
                        child: Image.memory(
                          schedule_image[i],    //'img/ico.jpg',
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Divider();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

below is the data that I want to display.

```
I/flutter ( 4830): {alternateno: [7845659877, 9865358577], coachaddress: [anand vihar, delhi, delhi, Gautam Budha nagar, noida], coachemail: [abc@gmail.com, xyz@gmail.com], coachid: [1, 2], coachname: [abc Coaching, xyz Coaching], primary_number: [9865328899, 9898557898], userid: [1, 1]}
```

please help...

Comment: if `schedule_image = image;`  then `schedule_image` should be provided as array of bytes instead of one byte (`schedule_image[i]`), so try `Image.memory(schedule_image, fit: BoxFit.fill)`

Comment: Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' - this is the error that i am getting with this change.

Comment: `Uint8List schedule_image;` instead of `var`

Comment: yes, I did that getting the same error.

Comment: need to debug, can You put full response to Your question? Need to check that base64 blob

Comment: can you elaborate on what i need to give?

Comment: You've to put that json response to Your question or to pastebin.com service. Need to check what kind of data You're parsing. Since Image.memory and convertion methods are used correctly. Need example data to check reason why it's not working on Your part

Comment: I think initially that variable is empty so it cannot render, try this:
`child: schedule_image != null ? Image.memory(schedule_image, fit: BoxFit.fill) : Placeholder(fallbackWidth: 500, fallbackheight: 400)`

Comment: the data i am getting from the MySQL database and the response i have given above.

Comment: `{alternateno: [7845659877, 9865358577], coachaddress: [anand vihar, delhi, delhi, Gautam Budha nagar, noida], coachemail: [abc@gmail.com, xyz@gmail.com], coachid: [1, 2], coachname: [abc Coaching, xyz Coaching], primary_number: [9865328899, 9898557898], userid: [1, 1]}`  **- there is no** `scheduleImage` **field** - so Your `var blob = null` since there is no such field

Comment: {classid: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], courseid: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], date: [Fri, 18 Dec 2020 00:00:00 GMT, Sun, 20 Dec 2020 00:00:00 GMT, Mon, 21 Dec 2020 00:00:00 GMT, Tue, 22 Dec 2020 00:00:00 GMT, Wed, 23 Dec 2020 00:00:00 GMT, Thu, 24 Dec 2020 00:00:00 GMT], scheduleimage: [b'[]', b'[]', b'[]', b'[]', b'[]', b'[]']}  - here you go

Comment: @num8er it is showing placeholder

Comment: now I see Your issue, You've multiple images, and You want to decode one of them and show? am I correct?

Comment: it's showing placeholder since initially it has to show placeholder until state changes (data is fetched)

Comment: yes i have a list of images and i want to show all of them in list view .

Comment: so wait I'm writing answer